# CSS: set background color paddings of div

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the this codepen: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVOJeb). I have the following html:

```
<fieldset class="rangeset">
    <div class="range-container">
        <label for="question_three_radio_01">
            <input id="question_three_radio_01" name="question_three" type="radio" value="0" /><span></span>
        </label>
        <label for="question_three_radio_02">
            <input id="question_three_radio_02" name="question_three" type="radio" value="1" /><span></span>
        </label>
        <label for="question_three_radio_03">
            <input id="question_three_radio_03" name="question_three" type="radio" value="2" /><span></span>
        </label>
        <label for="question_three_radio_04">
            <input id="question_three_radio_04" name="question_three" type="radio" value="3" /><span></span>
        </label>
        <label for="question_three_radio_05">
            <input id="question_three_radio_05" name="question_three" type="radio" value="4" /><span></span>
        </label>
        <label for="question_three_radio_06">
            <input id="question_three_radio_06" name="question_three" type="radio" value="5" /><span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And this CSS:

```
[type="radio"] {
    border: 0; 
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    height: 1px; margin: -1px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 1px;
}

.radio-label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 0;
}

[type="radio"] + span:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: -5px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
    margin-right: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
    background: #A4B162;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #48530D;
}

fieldset {
    border: 2px solid #48530D;
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.rangeset {
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.range-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

What i now want to do is to create a background color which is as thick and as wide as all radiobuttons together. I tried to set the background color of the div but the result was this: [CodePen 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmoQKR)

The background color set here is already as thick as the radiobuttons (so its perfect) but if you take a look at the very right radiobutton you see that the background color is wider than all the radiobuttons together. I want the background color to stop at the end of the last radiobutton.

Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: Can't see any background stripes in the 2nd demo. Could you provide more details on where you need the padding?

Comment: Really? You see no green stripe in the background of the radio buttons in the second codepen i posted? If i open the link i can see it. The stripe is too thick. I need it thinner and just to be as wide as the radiobuttons. you can see at the very right radiobutton that the stripe continues further. Tested the CodePen 2 i posted on chrome, firefox and opera. I can see it everywhere

Comment: I see no stripes. All I see is a black border with some padding (white) area and a green solid inner fill.

Comment: I never said "stripes" i said "stripe" and yes im talking about the "green solid inner fill"

Comment: I don't get you, please elaborate.

Comment: I edited my opening post. maybe it gets more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have been confused setting your margins.

.rangeset reset `padding-right to 0;`

span:before gives a `margin-right` too.

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojJOWM?editors=110

```css
[type="radio"] {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.radio-label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 0;
}

[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: -5px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #000;
  margin-right: 20px;/* remove this from last label span */
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  background: #A4B162;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #48530D;
}

fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #48530D;
  padding: 27px 20px;
  display: block;
}

.rangeset {
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-right: 0px;/* it doesn-t remove the margin-right of last label span:before */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.range-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #A4B162;
}

label:last-child span:before {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rangeset">
  <div class="range-container">
    <label for="question_three_radio_01">
      <input id="question_three_radio_01" name="question_three" type="radio" value="0" /><span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="question_three_radio_02">
      <input id="question_three_radio_02" name="question_three" type="radio" value="1" /><span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="question_three_radio_03">
      <input id="question_three_radio_03" name="question_three" type="radio" value="2" /><span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="question_three_radio_04">
      <input id="question_three_radio_04" name="question_three" type="radio" value="3" /><span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="question_three_radio_05">
      <input id="question_three_radio_05" name="question_three" type="radio" value="4" /><span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="question_three_radio_06">
      <input id="question_three_radio_06" name="question_three" type="radio" value="5" /><span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

1 - I changed `.range-container` to the following:

```
.range-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position:relative;
}
```

2 - Then added:

```
.range-container:before {
  display:block;
  width:calc(100% + 20px);
  height:calc(100% + 27px + 20px);
  position:absolute;
  top:-27px;
  left:-20px;
  content: '';
  z-index:-1;
  background: #A4B162;
}
```

Here's the codepen:
http://codepen.io/Meligy/pen/EVGJmb